# c# program to forward tcp port 13000 to rdp port 3389?

Tags: c#, portforwarding, rdp

I am trying to write a test program that will listen for tcp on port 13000 and the forward it to port 3389. It starts to work in that it passes data back and forth about 6 or 7 times but then the initial socket drops.

The program crashes with a socket exception on line 47 which is:
var bytesRead = _forwardSocket.EndReceive(ar);

The exception is 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'

Below is a screenshot of the program running. What am I missing?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace PortForwardTest
{
    public class AsynchronousSocketListener
    {
        private static Socket _forwardSocket;
        private static Socket _rdpSocket;
        private static readonly byte[] _forwardBuffer = new byte[8192];
        private static readonly byte[] _rdpBuffer = new byte[8192];

        public static void Main()
        {
            var ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
            var ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            var localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 13000);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
            var listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            listener.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, listener);

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
            Console.Read();

        }

        public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Get the socket that handles the client request.  
            var listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            _forwardSocket = listener.EndAccept(ar);

            _forwardSocket.BeginReceive(_forwardBuffer, 0, _forwardBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReadCallback, null);
        }

        public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ReadCallback");
            // Read data from the client socket.
            var bytesRead = _forwardSocket.EndReceive(ar);
            Console.WriteLine($"ReadCallback bytes read: {bytesRead}");

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                SendToRdpServer(bytesRead);
            }
            _forwardSocket.BeginReceive(_forwardBuffer, 0, _forwardBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReadCallback, null);
        }


        private static void SendToRdpServer(int bytesRead)
        {
            if (_rdpSocket == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("**** Establishing the connection to the RDP server");
                var ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.3.2");
                var ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
                var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 3389);

                // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
                _rdpSocket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                _rdpSocket.Connect(endPoint);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Sending the data to the RDP server");
            _rdpSocket.Send(_forwardBuffer,0, bytesRead, SocketFlags.None);
            _rdpSocket.BeginReceive(_rdpBuffer, 0, _rdpBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReadCallbackFromRdpServer, null);

        }

        public static void ReadCallbackFromRdpServer(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ReadCallbackFromRdpServer");
            // Read data from the client socket.
            var bytesRead = _rdpSocket.EndReceive(ar);
            Console.WriteLine($"ReadCallbackFromRdpServer bytes read: {bytesRead}");

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Relaying the data back");
                _forwardSocket.Send((_rdpBuffer),0, bytesRead, SocketFlags.None);
            }
            _rdpSocket.BeginReceive(_rdpBuffer, 0, _rdpBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReadCallbackFromRdpServer, null);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Here is an updated image of the output showing the RDP connection is only done once.

[image]

Comment: The error is due to you trying to open a connection that is already open .  You can only have one connection with the same three parameters 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port number.  Inside the SendToRdpServer you are doing a connect which means every time you sent you are trying to open the same connection which was not closed.

Comment: No. That’s not it. I only open the connection once. See the if statement checking if the socket is null

Comment: Socket null doesn't necessarily mean the connection is also closed.

Comment: No but 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host' does. Besides That exception is on the _forwardSocket not the _rdpSocket.

Comment: Keep in mind this code is just a test the logic 'if (_rdpSocket == null)' is intended to see if the _rdpSocket is not set up and thus set it up and connect. Sorry, jdweng, you're barking up the wrong tree on this one.

Comment: No I'm not.  The error means the connection already exists (or previous connection didn't close).  You can use from cmd.exe >Netstat -a to see the connection state.  You cannot call SendToRdpServer multiple times because each time it opens the same connection and will fail the second time it is called.

Comment: I can call SendToRdpServer multiple times because the first time sets _rdpSocket to NOT NULL and thus only tries to open the connection ONCE.

Comment: Your logic is inconsistent.  You say you are failing on line 47.  So if null you should get there once.  But then you say it fails after 6 or 7 tries.  Both cannot be possible.

Comment: Hi jdweng, I have updated the program and added an image showing that the connection is made only once to the rdp server. I've added an image of the exception too

Comment: Use a sniffer a compare to the console output.  Look in the sniffer for [FIN] and see which direction the [FIN] starts to see if closing was from client or server.   Also from cmd.exe >Netstat -a and see what the status of the connection on both client and se